# Docker proper redirect link

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, react-router

I have Dockerfile:

```
FROM cloudron/base:0.10.0
ENV PATH /usr/local/node-6.9.5/bin:$PATH
WORKDIR /tmp
COPY package.json /tmp/
RUN npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ && npm install
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN cp -a /tmp/node_modules /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:production" ]
```

if I run this by:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 -t somename/appname
```

then 
going to `http://localhost:8000` works fine
but if I want go to `http://localhost:8000/about` I get error:

```
Cannot GET /about
```

What should I do to make it well configured ?
Of course my react app, works fine with such link using in development start.

EDIT:

```
 "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "compile": "node build/scripts/compile",
    "build": "npm run clean && cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm run compile",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node build/scripts/start",
    "start:production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node build/scripts/start",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test karma start build/karma.config",
    "test:watch": "npm test -- --watch",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix"
  },
```

looks like my start:production is not good..

Comment: try to check if the page is served inside the container, for example with curl: `curl localhost:8000/about`.  If so check on which IP address the application server is listening (try listening on 0.0.0.0 to see if it works).

Comment: as i said, using npm start ( development mode ) this works fine.. problem is while using docker